# phpunit is letting a test pass when it should fail

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm following along with this Laracasts video https://laracasts.com/lessons/tdd-by-example

In the lesson we are creating a test in PHPunit for the `store` method on the `SupportController`

Here is what the test looks like so far.

```
public function test_submits_support_request_upon_form_submission()
    {
        $this->call('POST', 'support/store', ['name' => 'john']);

    }
```

I do not have a rout yet that matched `'support/store'`. 
When I run this I get no falures. In the video, he got an error `Synphoy\Component\HttpKernal\Exeception\NotFoundHttpException`

This makes sense becase the route the test is trying to hit doesn't exist yet. I'm using Laravel 5 and he's using 4 in the video. Is there something I need to change in order to get this to work correctly?

Comment: So what do you see if you send that request manually? What is the response?

Comment: When I send it manually I see this error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:` , which is what I expect

Comment: And what about HTTP? What status is returned?

Comment: If you add `$this->assertResponseStatus(404);` after the call to the route, does your test still pass? If it does, change it to 200. Then you'll know when your route is working. Alternatively, change it to `$this->assertResponseOk();`

Comment: Actually, when I git the `404` back it was after I created the rout and had this inside my `store` action `dd(Input::all());` . That was giving me he `404`. After taking out the rout (which is how it was when I originally asked the question) I got a 500 response. When I add this to the test `$this->assertResponseStatus(500)` it passes, when I change it to `200` it fails. So it looks like the test is hitting the route. I just though the test was supposed to let me know there is no rout when I used this `$this->call('POST', 'support/store', ['name' => 'john']);`

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that Laravel 5 doesn't throw an exception when you call the `call` method -- even if it doesn't match a route.  If a test method doesn't throw an exception, and contains no assertions, it will pass.  Although, that said, depending on how you've configured `phpunit` it should be warning you that your test contains no assertions.

I'd start with

- What does `$this->call('POST', 'support/store', ['name' => 'john']);` return?
- Are you sure your test class is included in the run?
- Are you sure the test runner runs your class?

Answer these, and I suspect an answer to your question will emerge.

Comment: 1. I don't know how to see what `$this->call('POST', 'support/store', ['name' => 'john']);` 2. My test class is extending `TestCase` - `class SupportControllerTest extends TestCase` , so I think that answers that question. 3.  I am sure the test class is included in the run, because if I do something like remove  a semi colon in the actual `SuportController.php`  the test breaks